# Using NS2 to simulate 802.15.4 gives rise to a bug

Tags: c++, linux, ns2, zigbee

I'm trying to simulate a large number of randomly generated 802.15.4 networks. I start 250 FFDs, up to 50 RFDs and a PAN Coordinator. The transmission range is set to 40m, the topology size is 500m x 500m and the simulation ends after 1800s (30 minutes). Each RFD creates one CBR link to the PAN Coordinator starting at 0s and sending all through the simulation at 2s intervals. Packet size is 70 [bytes].

Now, for the important part - since it's a "large" simulation, I use the "Scheduler/Heap" scheduler. I say that this is important because I started to get errors of the form  (in retrospect, probably isn't important, but it was a mayor clue that something was wrong!):

"ns: scheduler going backwards in time from 'x' to 'y'"

So, normally, I dismembered the scheduler.cc, scheduler.h and heap.h files in a search for an answer. After a full 12 hours of debugging (I am neither a proficient Linux user, nor a good c++ programmer) I finally found the cause/symptom - a packet already contained in the heap would change (increase) it's time value. This would, of course, totally mess up the heap structure and eventually this packet would be extracted and processed, but the next packet would fail because it would have a smaller time value.

Now, this behavior is a telltale sign of a change-by-reference, and after a few more hours of pathetic attempts of using gdb, I managed to find the culprit - the `void Phy802_15_4Timer::start(double wtime)` function in wpan/p802_15_4phy.cc. It sets the uid_ of a "nullEvent" to 0 every time it's called AND has a single packet/event reference to it. Gotcha! Furthermore, I figured out that the CCAHandler implementation was the one to blame and tracked it down to a single method call - `void Phy802_15_4::PLME_CCA_request()` in the same file. I checked and, would you know it - the CCAH handler was still active (flag active in Phy802_15_4Timer) when its start method was called (again)!

Finally, here's my question: seeing as other methods check the "active" flag for other handlers before actually invoking the start function (and, subsequently, calling the cancel method of said handler if it's active at that moment), I modified the code the the function in question to the following:

```
void Phy802_15_4::PLME_CCA_request()
{
    if (trx_state == p_RX_ON)
    {
        // THIS IS WHAT I ADDED - START
        if(CCAH.active) {
            CCAH.cancel();
        }
        // THIS IS WHAT I ADDED - END

        //perform CCA
        //refer to sec 6.7.9 for CCA details
        //we need to delay 8 symbols
        CCAH.start(4/getRate('s')); // 2.32 change: start CCA at the end of 4th symbol
    }
    else
        mac->PLME_CCA_confirm(trx_state);
}
```

With this change, I get no more errors (yay!). But, I'm not sure if this is a valid change... My knowledge of both NS2 and 802.15.4 is very limited and I need this to work, but at the same time, I'm afraid to touch anything for the risk of getting experimental results that are - wrong!

Is this an OK approach? Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Hello! Sorry if I sounded rude - it was not my intention in the least. It's just that I've been trying to get answers to several questions concerning ns2 in the last few years but have rarely gotten a single response. Most of the references on the web are 10, 20 years old, many pages that are referenced, even in official documentation, are long gone and unavailable. Anyways, I was just trying to justify asking a ns2 related question here, and not on the ns2 google group. I tried getting some answers there more than once already, but with no success. Was your experience with ns2 different?

Comment: I haven't used it. Looking into it I might agree that the community may be small. The last release was 7 years ago. If your intention wasn't to be rude, may I ask what kind of reaction you were expecting on *Having seen some NS2 questions here (some even had answers. WOW!)*? (and further on, may I suggest to remove the 2 top paragraphs?)

Comment: To be honest, I was hoping for a sympathetic reaction from people that have been in the same situation I'm in now. But you may be correct in removing the first two paragraphs - I would hate to put off someone willing to help by sounding rude...

Comment: When in doubt stick to stating the problem and anything directly relevant to the situation, not anecdotal information about the community, what you had for breakfast, or your hopes and aspirations in life. These digressions can come across as rambling, rude, or both. Stay positive, stay focused, and hope for the best!

Comment: Mac802.15.4 : Segmentation fault is known to happen with most newly written simulations files. Besides the original wpan examples, very few "news" → https://drive.google.com/file/d/16oa9yCrVTJOdx943zCGMSdK-C7iBzOPZ/view?usp=sharing ... ( All ~2500 ns2 simulations https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing )